# Postgres cursor update each row in separate transaction

Tags: postgresql

I have a million-row table in Postgres 13 that needs a one-time update of each row: the (golang) script will read the current column value for each row, transform it, then update the row with the new value, for example:

```
DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT v FROM users;

FETCH c1;
-- read and transform v
UPDATE users SET v = ? WHERE CURRENT OF c1;
-- transaction committed

FETCH c1;
...
```

I'm familiar with cursors for reading, but have a few requirements for writing that I'm struggling to find the right settings for:

1. I don't want it all to run in a single huge transaction, which is the default with cursors, since the change set will be large and it will take a while. I'd rather each update be its own transaction, and I can re-run the idempotent script again if it fails for any reason. I'm aware of `DECLARE WITH HOLD` to have the cursor span transactions, but...
2. By default the data read by the cursor is "insensitive" (a snapshot from when the cursor was first created), but I would like the latest data for each row with FETCH in case there has been a subsequent update. The solution to that is to [use `FOR UPDATE` in the cursor query to make it "sensitive,"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-declare.html) but that is not allowed together with `WITH HOLD`. I would prefer the row lock you get with `FOR UPDATE` to prevent the read-then-write race condition between FETCH and UPDATE, but it's not mandatory

How can I iterate all rows and update them one at a time without having to read everything into memory first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the cursor be WITH HOLD, but select the pk rather than v.  Then in the loop, select the now-current v from the table based on the pk (rather than `current of main`), and update it using the pk.

Comment: feels clunky, but I guess the only option, thanks